# How to leave specific values and print next one in python for loop?

Tags: python

i want to leave `''` vacant number from list and print data

```
numbers= ['123','456','','789']
```

I want result like this:

```
123
456
789
```

Comment: Please, detail your tryouts and struggles. What do you have so far?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop and an `if` statement to catch empty strings, you could do the following:

```py
for number in numbers:
    if not number:
        continue
    else:
        print(number)


# prints this
123
456
789
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the string in numbers is empty or not with `if`

```
for num in numbers:
    if num:
        print(num)
```

`''` - the empty string is `False`-ey so it won't be printed